# Do fins with slightly different masses but the same surface area affect the stability of a rocket?

Tags: rockets, aerodynamics, astrodynamics, amateur-rocketry, high-altitude-launch

Each of four fins of a rocket are of slightly different masses like( 0.204, 0.2, 0.199 and 0.19 kg). If they have the same surface area, will that severely affect the stability (spin) during flight? I was going to put a layer of paint to add the difference.

When calculating the angular moment is the distance taken from the center of gravity or the base of the rocket nozzle up to the centroid of the fins?

Comment: This might be better suited for a [high-power rocketry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-power_rocketry)  forum

Comment: What fraction of the total mass of the rocket are the fin-mass *differences* (during the flight when fins are most necessary) ? Also what are the uncertainties in the location of the centre of mass and the thrust line ? These might have a much larger effect that the fin-mass difference.

Comment: Thank you @AJN The fins weigh about 0.7 kg in total out of 25 kg of the vehicle weight.  I am not sure what you mean by uncertainties in location of cg and the thrust line, but I am looking into it.

Comment: Distance (and angle) from CG for inertial effects. Distance from velocity axis for aerodynamic effect. Realistically, on amateur rocket... it does not matter. especially if your rocket has a good spin. Consider that a fireworks with the stick attached **to the side** flies roughly straight. There is no ways your fins are nearly that far off-balance. Fins are an extremely brute-force, inefficient, yet very effective and forgiving way of stabilizing a basic rocket. If you want to worry, worry about their behavior when approaching and passing mach1. Trans-sonic does weird to aerodynamics

Comment: From a purely theoretical standpoint, and simplifying the problem:
Fins with the exact same surface area and geometry will generate the same forces (lift force is a function of lift coefficient (geometry dependent), dynamic pressure (air density and velocity dependent), and surface area.

But assuming they are installed axisymettrically, the four fins with different masses will shift the center of mass of the rocket off the central axis. So the forces will be balanced around the center, but your CoM is shifted and there may be an instability due to an induced moment/rotation